# Youtube iPhone issue

Tags: iphone, html, web, hyperlink, youtube

I want to play a youtube video on a website trough a hyperlink (a website for iOS devices such as iPhone/iPod/iPad). This works almost perfect except I have one big issue:

• When the video is done, I do not get the "done" button in the top left of the youtube video you would expect to bring you back to the website from where you clicked the youtube hyperlink.

Instead, it seems the youtube iphone app is opened and "done" reads "back". Pressing back brings the user to the youtube app main page, to return to the website he has to double tap the home button to go to safari and select the website.

The result I am looking for is the same that happends when you click on an embedded youtube movie, instead of in my case: a hyperlinked youtube movie (this will play in fullscreen and displays a done button which brings you back to the webpage that movie was embedded on).

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a iOS developer, but I have an iPhone and watch quite a few videos on it.
As far as I can tell, iOS opens the YouTube app whenever you click on a YouTube link ... and stays in it after you've finished playing. That's what you mean by "there's now done button".

Doing a little research, I found [this post](http://www.tipb.com/2010/07/25/style-youtube-embed-flashfree-iphone-video/). To embed yt videos in your site, use an iframe, like so:

```
<iframe type="text/html" width="640" height="385"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

where VIDEO-ID is the string you find at the end of yt links (e.g. C8Wu3Bps9ic in http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C8Wu3Bps9ic).

Hope that helps!